# How would I shorten this jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm very new to jQuery, so please be gentle.

I found two articles online:

1. Adding a fade-in/fade-out to a rollover sprite with jQuery:
   http://css-tricks.com/fade-image-within-sprite/
   (Way The Third: Legacy Support version)
2. [Animating a Hover with jQuery](http://www.incg.nl/blog/2008/hover-block-jquery/)

I've used both of these examples and managed to make them work together:

http://www.marccohen.co.uk/dev/menu_example.htm

The rollover fade sprites in one list also trigger the animated hovers in the other list, and vice versa. Trouble is the resulting jQuery I have is 'very' long and being so new to this, I've got no idea how I can shorten it:

```
$(function() {
$(".menuicon1")
.find("span")
.hide()
.end()
.hover(function() {
    $(this).find("span").stop(true, true).fadeIn({duration:300});
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide1').find('img').animate({top:'192px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
}, function() {
    $(this).find("span").stop(true, true).fadeOut({duration:300});
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide1').find('img').animate({top:'276px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
});
$(".menuicon2")
.find("span")
.hide()
.end()
.hover(function() {
    $(this).find("span").stop(true, true).fadeIn({duration:300});
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide2').find('img').animate({top:'192px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
}, function() {
    $(this).find("span").stop(true, true).fadeOut({duration:300});
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide2').find('img').animate({top:'276px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
});
$(".menuicon3")
.find("span")
.hide()
.end()
.hover(function() {
    $(this).find("span").stop(true, true).fadeIn({duration:300});
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide3').find('img').animate({top:'192px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
}, function() {
    $(this).find("span").stop(true, true).fadeOut({duration:300});
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide3').find('img').animate({top:'276px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
}); 
$(".menuicon4")
.find("span")
.hide()
.end()
.hover(function() {
    $(this).find("span").stop(true, true).fadeIn({duration:300});
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide4').find('img').animate({top:'192px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
}, function() {
    $(this).find("span").stop(true, true).fadeOut({duration:300});
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide4').find('img').animate({top:'276px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
}); 
$(".menuicon5")
.find("span")
.hide()
.end()
.hover(function() {
    $(this).find("span").stop(true, true).fadeIn({duration:300});
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide5').find('img').animate({top:'192px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
}, function() {
    $(this).find("span").stop(true, true).fadeOut({duration:300});
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide5').find('img').animate({top:'276px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
}); 
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide1').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').animate({top:'192px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
    $('.menuicon1').find("span").stop(true, true).fadeIn({duration:300});
}, function(){
    $(this).find('img').animate({top:'276px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
    $('.menuicon1').find("span").stop(true, true).fadeOut({duration:300});
});
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide2').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').animate({top:'192px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
    $('.menuicon2').find("span").stop(true, true).fadeIn({duration:300});
}, function(){
    $(this).find('img').animate({top:'276px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
    $('.menuicon2').find("span").stop(true, true).fadeOut({duration:300});
});         
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide3').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').animate({top:'192px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
    $('.menuicon3').find("span").stop(true, true).fadeIn({duration:300});
}, function(){
    $(this).find('img').animate({top:'276px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
    $('.menuicon3').find("span").stop(true, true).fadeOut({duration:300});
});             
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide4').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').animate({top:'192px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
    $('.menuicon4').find("span").stop(true, true).fadeIn({duration:300});
}, function(){
    $(this).find('img').animate({top:'276px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
    $('.menuicon4').find("span").stop(true, true).fadeOut({duration:300});
});             
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide5').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').animate({top:'192px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
    $('.menuicon5').find("span").stop(true, true).fadeIn({duration:300});
}, function(){
    $(this).find('img').animate({top:'276px'},{queue:false,duration:150});
    $('.menuicon5').find("span").stop(true, true).fadeOut({duration:300});
});                                 
});
```

Really appreciate any suggestions...

Comment: Write a function/extend jQuery, pass in the digit (the only thing changing between each blob of code), and call it for each element (if refactored to a function) or on a list of selectors (if extending jQuery).

Comment: You may not be aware of it, but there is a codereview.stackexchange.com for generally reviewing large amounts of code. (There's nothing wrong with your question here, but you might want to use codereview, too.)

Comment: Short of minifying the code, not really no.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dave-Newton already mentioned correctly, in order to shorten any piece of repetitive code, you have to **identify** the part that repeat over and over again and those being **unique**.

In your case there a (as far as I can see) two major blocks of code.

```
$(".menuicon1")
  .find("span")
  .hide()
  .end()
  .hover(function() {
    $(this)
      .find("span")
      .stop(true, true)
      .fadeIn({ duration: 300 });
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide1')
      .find('img')
      .animate({ top: '192px' },{ queue:false, duration: 150 });
  }, function() {
    $(this)
      .find("span")
      .stop(true, true)
      .fadeOut({ duration: 300 });
    $('ul.hover_block li.slide1')
      .find('img')
      .animate({ top: '276px' },{ queue: false, duration: 150 });
  });
```

Apparently only the number suffix for the css-classes differ in each call. So you might simply create a function that takes a number input and adds that to the dynamic parts:

```
function createBlockHover(blockNumber) {
  $(".menuicon" + blockNumber)
    .find("span")
    .hide()
    .end()
    .hover(function() {
      $(this)
        .find("span")
        .stop(true, true)
        .fadeIn({ duration: 300 });
      $('ul.hover_block li.slide' + blockNumber)
        .find('img')
        .animate({ top: '192px' },{ queue:false, duration: 150 });
    }, function() {
      $(this)
        .find("span")
        .stop(true, true)
        .fadeOut({ duration: 300 });
      $('ul.hover_block li.slide' + blockNumber)
        .find('img')
        .animate({ top: '276px' },{ queue: false, duration: 150 });
    });
}
```

After that you still might reduce the procedure within the hover call,
as that one does the animation and fading. Top and fade direction (In/Out) differ here:

```
function fadeBlocks(blockNumber, fadeIn, top) {
  // fade the first block
  $('.menuicon' + blockNumber)
    .find("span")
    .stop(true, true)
    [fadeIn ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut']({ 
      duration: 300 
    });

  // move the second
  $('ul.hover_block li.slide' + blockNumber)
    .find('img')
    .animate({ top: top + 'px' }, { queue: false, duration: 150 })
}

function createBlockHover(blockNumber) {
  $(".menuicon" + blockNumber)
    .find("span")
    .hide()
    .end()
    .hover(function() {
      fadeBlocks(blockNumber, true, 192);
    }, function() {
      fadeBlocks(blockNumber, false, 276);
    });
}
```

I hope that shows the process a little, so you'd know how to process with the latter part of your code.

For more information take a look the principle of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code.

Comment: Thanks for this.
RE: your first suggestion: I can certainly see what you are getting at but I'm not quite understanding how to make function createBlockHover(blockNumber) actually work.